# 3.3v input in a 1.8v logic question

Tags: voltage, logic-level

In a board design there's a mistake in the voltage level to control a reset pin (Signal RESETB). It should be 1.8v but it is driven by a 3.3v level.

The datasheet shows the next info:

[image]

It looks like the max level is 3.6v for VDDIO but RESETB max. level depends of VDDIO selected, would it be properly detected the RESETB as a logic high at 3.3V?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Adding  device maximum ratings table:

[image]

Comment: What is VDDIO in your board? If it's 1.8 you should limit the reset voltage to that.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks for your comment, the VDDIO is 1.8v and yes the reset voltage should be 1.8v too, but unfortunately there's a mistake and this signal is 3.3v, so  I wanted to know if with the given max. ratings it would work with 3.3v without damaging the device?

Comment: I'd be busy with razor blade, resistors and patch wire if it was mine.

Answer (score 1):

The reset input might be properly **detected** as a high level but it might also damage the "device". The 3.3V signal may forward-bias the input protection diodes for the digital inputs. If a large enough current flows through the diode it can damage the input pin.

You need to check the table of "Absolute Maximum Ratings" for the "device".

Comment: thanks for your answer, I added the Absolute Maximum Ratings, and it looks like it is a maximum value of 4V, even so do you think it might damage it?

Comment: The RESETB input isn't shown in the part of the maximum ratings table that you are showing us, so we can't make any conclusions from the information you provided. VDDIO appears to be a supply voltage, not an I/O pin voltage. You should give us a link to the datasheet for the device.

Comment: yes that´s right, I only posted part of the table than I thought was more related to the RESETB signal, here is the whole datasheet device:
https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/268/00001792A-467994.pdf